# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on a microservice with C# and ASP .NET Core 6 and I am trying to connect the docker image of the microservice with a docker image of SQL Server containers. I'm using docker compose for running them. But am getting this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'user'.

I have already tried several options I have found here but still getting the error.

My connection string is this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "dbname": "Server=sqls;Database=dbname;User ID=user; Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trusted_Connection=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
```

What else could I try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is obvious... your credentials are wrong.

Comment: I have checked my credentials, the code error was with a mistake in the question. I still have the problem

Comment: If thats not your actual error then post your actual error.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It will have more details as to the specific reason for the error, such as invalid database name.

Comment: Ensure you are using the 'sa' user, and specify a password that meets the minimum complexity requirements of sql server.  `Password` is not strong enough, but `P@ssw0rd!` is. Make sure you accept the end user license agreement as well, this is all spelled out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash

Comment: @AdamVincent seriously? Recommending the use of `sa`? One should almost never use `sa` instead one should create specific logins with the minimum required access rights.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DaleK I was talking about the initial connection.  If OP hasn't connected to the DB for the first time, with the `sa` account, then how could they have set up a new user account?

Answer (score 0):

If your login ID and password are correct, most likely your login is locked out

Anyway it is not a good practice to include connection string in docker-compose.yaml. There are several options for you, in your case you can use a .env file with Docker Compose, for example

```
services:   
   name_of_the_service:
      env_file: 
          - SQL.env
```